# jquery dialog box with iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, iframe

I'm trying to use the jquery ui dialog box to output an iframe. It doesn't seem to be working for me. I think I am making a syntax mistake somewhere- probably with quotation marks in the iframe. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<a href='' onclick=\"open_course_article('$userid','$title', 'remove', '$sel_course');\">Remove from Course</a>

   function open_course_article(userid,article,option,course) {
        $('<iframe src="article_course.php?option="+option+"&userid="+userid+"&course="+course+"&article="+escape(article)"/>').dialog({
        title: 'Add Article',
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        modal: true,
        }).width(570).height(370);
     }
```

Comment: Is your jQuery selector really split across 2 lines in your code? Did you look at your browser's Javascript error console?

Comment: nope it's not really split, stackoverflow did that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing single quotes with double quotes *for enclosing a string*, which does not work in programming.

```
$('<iframe src="article_course.php?option="+option+"&userid="+userid+"&course="+course+"&article="+escape(article)"
 />')
```

should be something more like:

```
$('<iframe src="article_course.php?option='+option+'&userid='+userid+'&course='+course+'&article='+escape(article)+'"
 />')
```

Comment: Because this most certainly does work in programming. You merely have to do it correctly.

Comment: @DarkFalcon You can't enter a string definition with a single quote, then end the same string definition with a double quote in any language...

Comment: But his string was a valid string. It just might not have opened the URL he expected. My point is still valid: you can use both single and double quotes in a string if you use them properly.

Comment: @DarkFalcon you can enclose double quotes, within a single quoted string, yes, but that clearly is not what I was referring to. My point is valid.

Comment: Then clarify what you mean. Don't say "doesn't work in programming". Say something like "You've mixed quotes incorrectly and here is how"

Answer (score -2):

The jquery selector you have specified is wrong. I believe you have an  tag somewhere in your html. Select iframe this way

```
  $('iframe').dialog{ ...}
```

or if you have other iframes in your html then you will have to provide some unique attribute...lets say id in which case:

```
   $('iframe #idvalue').dialog{ ...}
```

please show your html file for us to be able to help better

Comment: he is creating a new element, not selecting an existing one. in jQuery you do this just as he has shown `$('<div></div>')`.